# Postgres replication/replication to server outside firewall

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a way to have a postgresql database (running server version 9.1) replicated. I want the mirroring to be able to have one server (the slave) standing outside our firewall. I have been looking at slony and streaming replication - in both these cases, the slave server needs to talk back to the master, for security reasons, I would like that not to be the case. Ideally, I would like the master just to send the changes off to the slave without expecting any answers. are there any systems that act like this?

(Of course, I know that if the slave goes down, or for some other reason is not able to receive the data, the master will not know, but as we have other tools to keep an eye on server problems, this is acceptable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [log-shipping standby](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html) functions, which is really an extension of [continuous archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html).

You first configure PostgreSQL to write all[*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#CONTINUOUS-ARCHIVING-CAVEATS) changes to the Write-Ahead Log by saying:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
```

Once a log file is full (16 MB of writes) or a configurable timeout occurs (`archive_timeout`), PostgreSQL starts writing to the next log file, and it calls your `archive_command` with the filename of the log it just finished writing. Your `archive_command` would be a script that uses some other appropriate technology to push this log file off the master -- maybe you want to upload it to an object store like Amazon S3, or maybe you want to use SCP to push it straight onto the slave, or maybe you want to do something else entirely.

You'd set up the slave similarly to the master, except its data directory would include a `recovery.conf` saying `standby_mode = on`. If the master copies logs straight into the slaves' `pg_xlog` directory, you're done; if not, the slave will need a `restore_command` script to act as an inverse of `archive_command` and retrieve the indicated archive log from wherever you put it.

Lastly, copy over a base backup (as described in the continuous archiving documentation), start PostgreSQL, and your slave will be following the master without needing any direct communication.

Comment: Worked perfectly - just had to scratch my head a bit to set up the archive_command and restore_command ...

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/omniti-labs/omnipitr for archiving. That's what I use, and I'm satisfied.

Comment: I found this when I have the same issue of trying to get a one-way directional replication. Unfortunately i cannot get it to work and I created a question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197556/unable-to-start-the-standby-postgres-database hopefully you can enlighten me @MortenSickel