# unable to start the standby postgres database

Tags: postgresql, replication, restore, standby, write-ahead-logging

### Situation

I have 2 separate instances. Both running on Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Both have installed postgres 9.5 the following way:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
apt-get -y install postgresql-9.5
```

Version is 9.5.10

Then I named the instance representing master database `flanders` and the instance representing standby `willie`

I tested both instances on postgres user with `psql` All good.

I downloaded the [tar file of omnipitr-1.3.3](https://github.com/omniti-labs/omnipitr/releases) on both instances because version 2.0 is meant for postgres 10.

in the `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` of `flanders` I set the following:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
archive_command = '/var/lib/postgresql/omnipitr-1.3.3/bin/omnipitr-archive -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -l /var/log/omnipitr/archive-^Y-^m-^d.log -dr willie-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/master_wal_archive -s /var/lib/postgresql/.omnipitr/ "%p"'
archive_timeout = 120
max_wal_senders = 2
```

The `omnipitr-archive` script successfully sends the WAL file every 2 mins to `willie` using the `postgres` and leaves them inside `/var/lib/postgresql/master_wal_archive`

Now I then use `pg_basebackup` to backup the master database at `flanders` then I stopped the postgres to stop the continuous archiving every 2 mins

in `flanders` I run

```
postgres@flanders:~$ pg_basebackup -D backup -Ft -z -P -x
```

This creates a `base.tar.gz` inside `/var/lib/postgresql/backup`

I then use rsync to send the base file across to `willie`.

I stopped the postgres in willie as root using `service postgresql stop`. Then I run the following as `postgres` user:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/*

tar -xvC /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -f /var/lib/postgresql/base.tar.gz
```

went back as root user and turned on postgres using `service postgresql start`

Went as postgres user and psql and yes the database data is now an exact mirror as the master database.

So far so good.

### Proceeding with restore

Now here's when I start to have issues.

I stopped the postgres and went to /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main and created a recovery.conf

Inside this recovery.conf I have the following only.

```
standby_mode = on
restore_command='/var/lib/postgresql/omnipitr-1.3.3/bin/omnipitr-restore -l /var/log/omnipitr/restore.log -s /var/lib/postgresql/master_wal_archive/ %f %p'
```

which i take from https://github.com/omniti-labs/omnipitr/blob/master/doc/omnipitr-restore.pod#minimal-setup

Now I go to root user and start postgres up. It took longer than usual but I get an OK sign.

Then I tried to go to postgres and psql. I now have fatal error about the database starting up.

I then checked the postgres log file I get the following:

```
2018-02-10 17:34:53.185 CST [3896] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Cannot assign requested address
2018-02-10 17:34:53.185 CST [3896] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2018-02-10 17:34:53.197 CST [3897] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-02-10 17:30:10 CST
2018-02-10 17:34:53.198 CST [3897] LOG:  entering standby mode
2018-02-10 17:34:53.679 CST [3900] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2018-02-10 17:34:54.184 CST [3903] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:54.690 CST [3906] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:55.197 CST [3909] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:55.703 CST [3912] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:56.209 CST [3915] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:56.716 CST [3918] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:57.222 CST [3921] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:57.728 CST [3924] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:58.235 CST [3927] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:58.741 CST [3930] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:59.248 CST [3933] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-02-10 17:34:59.250 CST [3934] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

So now I realise I need to turn on `hot_standby` inside the `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf`

```
 hot_standby = on
```

Then when I now run `service postgresql start` as root, I didn't get an OK sign but I did get

```
2018-02-10 18:05:15.024 CST [4127] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Cannot assign requested address
2018-02-10 18:05:15.024 CST [4127] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2018-02-10 18:05:15.037 CST [4128] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2018-02-10 18:03:55 CST
2018-02-10 18:05:15.037 CST [4128] HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
2018-02-10 18:05:15.518 CST [4129] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2018-02-10 18:05:15.924 CST [4128] LOG:  entering standby mode
2018-02-10 18:05:15.924 CST [4128] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2018-02-10 18:05:15.926 CST [4128] WARNING:  WAL was generated with wal_level=minimal, data may be missing
2018-02-10 18:05:15.926 CST [4128] HINT:  This happens if you temporarily set wal_level=minimal without taking a new base backup.
2018-02-10 18:05:15.926 CST [4128] FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because wal_level was not set to "hot_standby" or higher on the master server
2018-02-10 18:05:15.926 CST [4128] HINT:  Either set wal_level to "hot_standby" on the master, or turn off hot_standby here.
2018-02-10 18:05:15.927 CST [4127] LOG:  startup process (PID 4128) exited with exit code 1
2018-02-10 18:05:15.927 CST [4127] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

So where did I go wrong with getting the standby server to be up?

#### UPDATE

As suggested by one of the answers, I have tried adding a `recovery.conf` into `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main` and then starting the postgres as user `root`.

Same result.

Comment: Seems like another postgresql is running. run this command `ps aux | grep postgres`

Comment: i got `root      1265  0.0  0.0  11732  2032 pts/0    S+   19:05   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres`

when grep `postmaster` I get `root      1267  0.0  0.0  11732  2028 pts/0    S+   19:06   0:00 grep --color=auto postmaster`

Comment: Understood, something gets corrupted, try to reset the XLOG (NOTE: don't use this in production server), Or may be some experts will guide here.

Comment: You talking abt the standby server yes?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have started the database and then stopped it before creating the `recovery.conf` file.  Once you start the database without a recovery.conf, it opens for write usage, or tries to, and then is no longer eligible to replay more log files.  (Although I don't understand why it led to the exact error message about wal_level=minimal).

Create the `recovery.conf` immediately after the `tar -x`.

Comment: Do I need to restart the Postgres after creating the recovery.conf?

Comment: didn't work. same issue.

Comment: You wouldn't restart, because you wouldn't have started it yet in the first place.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I started after I set the recovery conf I got the same result

Comment: I'd restart the master and then retake the base backup.  Maybe the original one was taken too early, before the changes to its config had taken effect.